# Huge data to show on browser using AngularJS, all the browsers are getting crased

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, serialization, json.net, bigdata

My task is to show Huge data on UI. DataBase is returning around 25 sets and 5 sets are having around 10000 rows and rest are having around 1000 rows, so total around 80k rows. I was trying it in demo application where I've created very basic WebApi, in which I am just getting data from DataBase and filling my class using SqlDaraReader(See below code).

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            HugeDataSetClass obj = new HugeDataSetClass();
            string connectionString = string.Empty;
            connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            string jsonResult;

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_testHugeData", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
   obj.obj1 = new BindingList<HugeDataModel>();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            HugeDataModel obj111 = new HugeDataModel();
                            obj111.id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                            obj111.name1 = reader.GetString(1); obj111.name2 = reader.GetString(2); obj111.name3 = reader.GetString(3); 
                            ...
                            ...
                            obj111.name89 = reader.GetString(89); obj111.name90 = reader.GetString(90);
                            obj.obj1.Add(obj111);
                        }
                        ...
                        ...
                        reader.NextResult();
                        obj.obj29 = new BindingList<HugeDataModel>();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            HugeDataModel obj1 = new HugeDataModel();
                            obj1.id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                            obj1.name1 = reader.GetString(1); obj1.name2 = reader.GetString(2); obj1.name3 = reader.GetString(3); 
                            ...
                            ...
                            obj1.name89 = reader.GetString(89); obj1.name90 = reader.GetString(90);
                            obj.obj29.Add(obj1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            jsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(jsonResult, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return response;
        }
```

In above code I am getting "OutOfMemory" exception while Serializing obj. If I comment this serialization code and response thing and return object of HugeDataSetClass then on browser(I've tried all the possible browsers) I get the data but before displaying it browser gets crashed. Below is my UI(AngularJs) code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test Page To Display Huge Data</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        table {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("hugeDataApp", []);
        app.controller("hugeDataController", function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.GetHugeData = function () {
                $http.get("http://localhost:60533/api/HugeData").then(
                    function (response) {
                        $scope.HugeDataSets = response.data;
                    }
            );
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="hugeDataApp" ng-controller="hugeDataController">
    <input type="button" id="btnLoad" value="Load" ng-click="GetHugeData()" />
    <br />
    <div id="div1">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in HugeDataSets.obj1">
                <td>{{x.id}}</td>
                <td>{{x.name1}}</td>
                <td>{{x.name2}}</td>
                <td>{{x.name3}}</td>
                ...
                ...
                <td>{{x.name89}}</td>
                <td>{{x.name90}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="div29" style="width: 100%">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in HugeDataSets.obj29">
                <td>{{x.id}}</td>
                <td>{{x.name1}}</td>
                <td>{{x.name2}}</td>
                <td>{{x.name3}}</td>
                ...
                ...
                <td>{{x.name89}}</td>
                <td>{{x.name90}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, if I show small amount of data say 1000 rows(worst case) and keep the original huge set at client side for further computation, will it work? And suppose I can keep huge data at client side but it's not allowing me to serialize it in WebApi, or I should not at all serialize it?

Comment: Why show 80k rows in a browser? who would actually find this useful?  Have you considered only showing the top 200?

Comment: Pagination is your friend

Comment: In my actual task I am gonna need this big set for some computation. So I need to hold it. In this demo application I can't perform original computation, so was trying to show on UI. So let me change my question a bit, can I hold this much big set at client side or still it's gonna crash? And even browser holds this big set still Newtonsoft serializer is throwing error or I should not serialize my data at all?

Comment: @sunil20000 - that's too many questions.  On stackoverflow the recommended format is [one question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).  Try to break your problem down into discrete pieces, and ask about each piece.  For c#/.Net related questions, please be sure to include the full `ToString()` output of the exception, including the message, traceback, and any inner exception(s).

Comment: You can use [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) if you are willing to pay the load and parse cost.

Comment: I'd recommend doing computing on the server side, so you don't need to sent all the data to client at once. So send just a small set of data to the client and use lazy loading to load more on demand.

Comment: @miensol I have no intention to show this data on UI, UI will show small part of it only, rest I want to prepare that small part and further computation. I don't wanna hit DB again for the same result sets. So I have to keep them on UI(I think so). So, when user triggers computation I can pass these sets to server and perform the computation.

Comment: @RomanHutnyk I need same sets for computation and I don't wanna hit DB again for the same sets, so need to keep them at client side. Is there any way to get rid of these sets at client side and don't need to hit DB again?

Comment: Sure, read it once from DB, cache on the server and do, whatever you need with it.

Comment: @RomanHutnyk can you suggest me how can I cache it at server level? Whole application is divided into 3 parts, one is webApi, second one is pure HTML pages and another one is middle tier. How can I cache it?

Comment: It should be implemented in web api. Here is simple implementation of server side caching: http://blog.developers.ba/simple-way-implement-caching-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: @RomanHutnyk thanks man.